# Wi-Fi issues with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10.
But the problem I face is that I do not see Enable Wifi option.
I referred to some videos saying that we need to use install third party software for wifi mp3 etc. while installing Ubuntu.
Is it correct and do I need to re-install OS? If not, then what else can be done. 
Please explain.....

Comment: You most likely lack the drivers for your wireless card, run this command `lspci | grep -i wireless` on a terminal and edit your answer with the output

Comment: @M.Becerra Not all wireless devices report as "wireless" in lspci. Here is an example: `Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI [1814:0301]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI [1043:837e]` May I suggest, instead: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: True that, you option is quite better then.  Thanks for explaining so.